# What is the most secure way to store post meta data in WP?

Tags: database, post-meta, security

Sony's recent security "holes" showed how unsafe it can be to store data unencrypted. As some of you may know, I 'm working on re-releasing the free CRM theme Driftwood.

What is the most secure way to store sensitive (ie non-public information) post meta in the database?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the type of data stored?

Comment: It could be email, phone numbers, or in some cases social security numbers. The new system allows for the site admin to store any text/media they want about/for a contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use bcrypt.

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Any good resources for how to do this in php or better yet hooking into WordPress?

Comment: @mfields - https://gist.github.com/972386 bcrypt usage in PHP